# Width not scaling on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, responsive-design

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but the main image is not shrinking on re-size of window (FIREFOX only).

URL: http://www.thesandiegocriminallawyer.com

What do I need to do to fix it?  I tried `width: 100%` in `.banner_right`, but that just messed everything up.

```css
.banner_right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_header">
  <div class="banner_right">
    <p>
      <img width="481" height="315" src="wp-content/uploads/2014/06/oz_main_new.jpg" alt="criminal lawyers san diego">
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me with width 100%

*Sorry its big*

[image]

UPDATE:

Change your image tag to:

```
<img src="wp-content/uploads/2014/06/oz_main_new.jpg" width="100%"/>
```

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't do that for me.  I'm not sure how to attach a screenshot, but trust me, it's not doing that. (I'm using FF for Mac).

Comment: Same, save a screen shot and upload it somewhre

Comment: Added.  Please see above.

Comment: Are you targeting the image specifically? Thats how it looks without width: 100%

Comment: I don't think so.  How should I do that?